# Test In progress plugin not showing blank

Tags: jenkins, testng

I followed the instructions given here:https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Test+In+Progress+Plugin

But unable to see any details of tests in progress.

Getting below exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not send message    at
>   org.jenkinsci.testinprogress.messagesender.MessageSender.flush(MessageSender.java:179)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.testinprogress.messagesender.MessageSender.testStarted(MessageSender.java:85)
>     at
>   org.imaginea.jenkins.plugins.testinprogress.testng.TestNGProgressRunListener.onTestStart(TestNGProgressRunListener.java:225)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1739)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1714)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:640)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)    at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:75)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:14)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)  at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
>     at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)  at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)    at
>   java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)     at
>   java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)     at
>   org.jenkinsci.testinprogress.messagesender.MessageSender.flush(MessageSender.java:177)
>     ... 14 more

Using TestNG and mvn clean verify to run my tests.

Comment: I am also getting same exception . It seems this testinprogress-testng plugin is older and no one is maintaining it

Comment: I feel so too..